# React Native fetch return exception ReferenceError: params is not defined

Tags: react-native, fetch

In React Natiave, I call API by "fetch" function

```
try {
        let response = await fetch(
            url,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                timeout: 10000,
                body: JSON.stringify(loginInfo)
            }
        )
        console.log(`URL: ${url} \nHTTP Status: ${response.status} params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
        if (response.status == "200") {
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            console.log(responseJson);
            this.setToken(responseJson.token);
            return responseJson;
        }
        else {

            return null;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
```

but got the error in the exception handler (in **catch** block):

ReferenceError: params is not defined
at ApiService.logIn$ (VM5 src\services\api-service\index.bundle:341)
at tryCatch (...\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (...\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:274)
at Generator.prototype. [as next] (...\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:97)
at tryCatch (...\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45)
at invoke (...\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135)
at ...\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:145
at tryCallOne (...\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37)
at ...\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123
at ...\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:277

In fact, when test by Postman, the server return HTTP Status code 203 but seem as fetch function cannot handle other status code except code 200.
What am I wrong in or how to handle other HTTP code in this case?

Comment: are you sure you have the params correct

Comment: its okay,happens with everyone

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the params imported in your header, else looks good.

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 1):

I think you've forget to pass params to the function. Seems the error is related to

`params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`

Where are you defining params? As parameter of the function? Are you passing it?

Comment: Yes, thank you! it just my stupid fault !!

Comment: No problem, typo happens :)